# Manage folder permissions so site members cannot rename folder but allow them to upload files under folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, custom-permission-level

I have a folder called "shared" in my document library, where users upload files and those files automatically get sent to AWS S3 bucket I have (using ms flow). Some users decided it would be a good idea for some reason to change the name of the "shared" folder and if the name is not shared then the file transfer will not work.

So I am wondering how to allow site members to upload files under the shared folder but not allow them to rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not create a new permission level called "Upload Only", and give *only* the "Add Items" list permission?  (This will automatically also select "View Items" in the item permissions and "View Pages" and "Open" in the Site Permissions.)

Then you could break permission inheritance on your "shared" folder, and change the permission level that site members have on that folder from Edit or Contribute or whatever it is to your new "Upload Only" permission level.